# Issue with a Trigger in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for a trigger which automatically inserts the highest price from table bids into the table opjects at the moment the bit 'closed?' turns from 0 to 1.

I've got the table Objects which has the values(Objectnumber, endprice (null), closed? (bit)(not null, default 0)).

The table bids with the value (Objectnumber,euro(prive of the bid),username)

This is what i currently got,

```
CREATE TRIGGER AF5 ON objects
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @objectnumber  numeric(10)
DECLARE @endprice       numeric(7,2)
DECLARE @closed?        bit
SET @objectnumber  = (SELECT objectnumber from inserted)
SET @endprice =(SELECT endprice from inserted)
SET @closed? =(SELECT closed? from inserted)
IF EXISTS     (     
                    SELECT subjectnumber
                    FROM  inserted
                    WHERE closed? = 1 AND endprice = NULL           
         )
BEGIN
    PRINT ('Found')
            update objects set endprice = ( 
                    SELECT MAX(b.euro) 
                    from bids b INNER JOIN objects v 
                    on @objectnumber = b.objectnumber  
                    where @closed? = 1  
            )
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Error', 1, 1)
            ROLLBACK
        END
    END
    GO
```

The error i keep getting is
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AF5, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 3834]
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: As the error states, one of your subqueries is returning more than 1 value, which isn't allowed. Run the subqueries separately, see which one returns multiple values and then update the subquery so it only returns one value (or reconfigure the code so you don't have a subquery if you need multiple values returned i.e. a JOIN or something different). You probably have multiple objectnumber values in your bids table that match the inserted data.

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR fundamental flaw. You are using scalar variables and assuming there will only ever be a single in inserted. In sql server triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. Your trigger needs to be set based and not use scalar variable like that.

Comment: `SET @objectnumber  = (SELECT objectnumber from inserted)` and similar lines are making the assumption that `inserted` has exactly one row. This isn't necessarily true for every `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. Somewhere in your scenario, multiple rows are being inserted or updated at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inserted` table can contains mutiply rows.

I delete your if condition because after update inside `IF` trigger can be fired again. If you want, check `@@ROWCOUNT` variable to get count of updated rows and compare it with count of rows in `inserted` table

```
CREATE TRIGGER AF5 ON objects
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN

    UPDATE O 
    SET endprice = B.EndPrice 
    FROM Objects        O
    INNER JOIN inserted I on O.objectnumber  = I.objectnumber 
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT EndPrice = MAX(B.euro) 
        FROM bids B
        WHERE B.objectnumber = O.objectnumber
    ) B
    WHERE I.[Closed?] = 1 AND I.endprice IS NULL AND B.EndPrice IS NOT NULL
END
```

Comment: this gives me a nesting error Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Comment: Weirdly i'm still getting the same "Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AF5, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 3859]
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)." It doesnt matter if i try to insert/update just one object or multiple.

Comment: Because @Mikhail Lobanov makes a common mistake. An update statement that affects zero rows will still cause the update trigger to execute. So you need to check for the existence of rows that need to be updated BEFORE you attempt to update them (while also only updating those same rows). check for existence using the same logic - join the inserted/deleted tables where the closed column changed to 1 from <anything else> and where end price is null.

Comment: Better yet - just put this logic into that code module that "closes" a bid and avoid the complexity of a trigger. Typically there are situations where one will need to manually update things in ways that cannot be anticipated.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know about this before